# Django password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128)

Tags: python, django, django-models

What relevance does the underscore have before ('password') in this line?

`password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128)`

I looked at the Django documentation and it states that the first parameter in the model field definition is a 'verbose name', however I cannot find what relevance the underscore has in this case?

The whole file I am looking at is:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The underscore is a common way of denoting that this string is available for translation:

```
 from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

This means the string will show up in tools that gather these strings and substitute them for translated strings (see [GNU gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) for example). This approach is used not only in Python but also in other programming languages / projects that require translated strings.

If you were to change the language of your Django website it would know to display a different string instead of `'password'` (depending on which translations are available, otherwise it'll default back to this English string).

Answer (score 1):

Underscore might be for localization/translation. Check the imports.
ex.

`from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _`

Answer (score 1):

In this link https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py
look for line containing below import

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

For international character set (Unicode) support, ugettext().You can use ugettext_lazy() as the default translation method for a particular file.